# Backbone - replacing the entire collection with one request

Tags: java, javascript, backbone.js

I have a Backbone Model,Collection, and a server side REST implementation.
Can i send a request to the server that will replace the entire collection?
I tried doing this with jqeury.post request but I'm not sure what the data should hold (an array of items with the model attributes? an array of models? a collection?), and what should the REST recieves as parameters(A java List? a Java array? a custom object containing a list of something?).

Any thoughts of this issues? am i missing something
Thanks!

Comment: Have you read [the official docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch)?

Answer (score 0):

according with documentation, you need use fetch

documentation here [Backbone Fetch]: http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch

fast example :

```
var newObject = new Object();
newObject.newvar1 = "newvar1"
newObject.newvar2 = "newvar2"

YOURMODEL.fetch({data: newObject,type:'POST'});
```